# How to use secure u-boot (HABv4) with mender on iMX6UL board

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot, mender

I implemented an open source solution called mender.io which provides OTA (over-the-air) software update to the iMX6UL board. I'm using Yocto's sumo distribution. Currently, a u-boot system is running on our board:

Firstly Poky's u-boot is basically working. On top of that, the ones from Variscite's u-boot.bbappend file are run, and the last ones are added from Mender's u-boot.bbappend file.
I want to run this structure using HAB (High Assurance Boot). So I want to sign only u-boot, SPL and kernel to run signed software. However, since we don't have a single u-boot, it doesn't seem possible or I don't understand. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: To me, signing should be done at image creation step, so it does not impact standard recipes? Maybe contact Mender.io support & NXP directly?

Comment: @memrekaraaslan I'm trying to collab mender.io with iMX6UL EVK (14 x 14) and struggling in that process. Could you offer any help?

Comment: Yes, I try to help as much as I can @Daniel

Comment: Thanks @memrekaraaslan you can contact me at botfordani on Twitter or mail me at daniel.selvan@jasmin-infotech.com